# Tomcat on startup White label error

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, server

I am trying to run Tomcat locally from command line. I downloaded and unzipped the Tomcat7 tar file. I got the following message when I tried to run the startup.sh script.

```
# sudo sh bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/cpatanaik/Desktop/test/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/cpatanaik/Desktop/test/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/cpatanaik/Desktop/test/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/cpatanaik/Desktop/test/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/cpatanaik/Desktop/test/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Now when I open the url "http://localhost:8080" in my browser, I am getting some white label error.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 18 15:36:04 CEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Can someone tell me how to access the default page after tomcat server startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Apparently I made a silly mistake. When I looked into the catalina log file inside logs folder, I found that I already had an instance of tomcat running on port 8080. So I was getting "Address already use" error messages in my log file.

Now that I have only one instance of Tomcat running, everything is working properly. So guys always check your log files before posting a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you